# How to do both, an alphabetical sort and an other specific sort for a column?

Tags: excel, vba

I am a beginner in VBA and I tried to do a specific sort after an aplhebitical sort.

Initially all data are shuffled and I applyed a sort to sort by alphabetical order with the following code:

```
Range ("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDwn)).Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
```

Please find below the first column of my excel sheet after the alphabetical sort.

```
   Column A
String_Atest_1
String_Btest_2
String_C60_APT
String_C60_BLD
String_C60_FUD
String_C60_TED
String_C63_APT
String_C63_BLD
String_C63_FUD
String_C63_TED
String_C64_APT
String_C64_BLD
String_C64_FUD
String_C64_TED
...
```

But my goal is to do an alphabetical sort with this specific order : `FUD, TED, BLD, APT`.

So the excepted result is:

```
   Column A
String_Atest_1
String_Btest_2
String_C60_FUD
String_C60_TED
String_C60_BLD
String_C60_APT
String_C63_FUD
String_C63_TED
String_C63_BLD
String_C63_APT
String_C64_FUD
String_C64_TED
String_C64_BLD
String_C64_APT
...
```

Someone can help me to do this please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You'll need to create a custom list I believe.

Comment: How about assigning numbers to your keywords( FUD->1, TED->2 etc) and creating an additional column with the corresponding numbers? You could then sort your data using this column.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without VBA (if you want to)

- Create your own custom sort list: **File** > **Options** > **Advanced** > **General**: **Edit Custom List** > Either **Import** or type your values. [Here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sort-data-using-a-custom-list-cba3d67a-c5cb-406f-9b14-a02205834d72) is a walkthrough.
- Select your range and in the ribbon, click **Data** > **Sort**.
- First rule is column B A-z
- Add a second rule for column C and under **Order** drop-down, select **Custom List** and select the list `FUD, Ted, BLD, APT`.
- Choose wheather or not you are using headers (I used them in example below)
- Confirm, and result should look like:

[image]

You can automate this procedure through VBA, there are examples around for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100944/code-an-excel-vba-sort-with-a-custom-order-and-a-value-containing-commas) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52848753/excel-vba-custom-order-sort).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I updated my question, indeed my strings are only on one column and not split on three columns. Results need to be in only one column.